# C++ curl kepp logged in to site, cookies

Tags: c++, cookies, curl

k so I already figured out how to login to site with post but now i have another problem.

My program just logins to site and gets its source but after loging in i want to move to next page and get its html.

it doesnt matter if after I put this code with different link it still gives me main page after login source

for example i login in index page but after i login i want to move to next page and then get its html . I hope you understand what i mean

thats not all my code. Just this section

```
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.tamo.lt/index.php");
    char *data="login_user=user&login_passwd=pass";
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
    curl_easy_perform( curl );
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.tamo.lt/dienynas.php");
    curl_easy_perform( curl );
```

Sorry iam bad at english.